# what does the NOT operator mean in this case?

Tags: c++

i've encountered this thing. I don't understand why you can both use cin and i also dont understand what it means.

```
      int val;
      if (!(cin >> val));
```

I don't understand what the if(!()) stands for and also able to type a character.

Comment: The `!` is logical negation: `! valid` is read as "not valid"

Comment: If you don't understand what the unary `!` operator does, it's time to spend some time with a [good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: well, i do but not if (!(cin>>var)). It uses cin still

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: its not if (!) its if(! () )

Comment: @TheDogeMaster: the inner parens are just for grouping/precedence, same as in `(a+b)*c`. They are not a function call or other magic.

Comment: mat what do you mean by grouping?

Comment: wait what does    if (cin>>val); mean?

Comment: "wait what does if (cin>>val); mean?" - It means you should spend more time with your books, learning the basics of the language.

Comment: @TheDogeMaster, Please answer this question: What does `if` do in c++?

Comment: @TheDogeMaster "_what does if (cin>>val); mean?_" Simple, it does whatever the `if` does, on the return value of `std::istream::operator>>`. Are you confused about `if (SomeFunction(someArgument))`, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does the ! mean after ...

! is a unary operator. In this case it is the logical NOT operator. If `expression` implicitly converted to `bool` results in true, then `!expression` is false and if `expression` implicitly converted to `bool` results in false, then `!expression` is true.

Comment: Wait this is a different question  but why does for (double dog; cin >> dog) works, how does dog get the value of cin?

Answer (score 1):

The ! operator in c++ is called NOT operator, it toggles true/false.
In the given code fragment: 

   `int val;
   if (!(cin >> val));`

The "if" condition will be true when the input value(cin>>) is "not" an integer. 
it can be further be clarified by the following code:

```
  int val;
  if (!(cin >> val)) 
     cout << "not an integer";
  else
      cout <<"integer";
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should not work as

```
if(!(cin>>val))// this is similar to if((cin>>val)==false)
```

This mean if the the input was not integer or something similar. 
I this what is really require is checking if is digit.

```
int val;
cin >>val; 
if(!isdigit(val))
{
 //goes in if false of else it skips the if statement.  
}
```

This is just an assumption (could be wrong).If need correct ans more detail is required, like what is the goal or...!

Comment: The example you posted is completely incorrect. `isdigit` checks if a **character** is a digit. You first read the input as an **integer**, and then you pass the result to a function that checks if a **character** is a digit.

Comment: oh yes understand